# One word for body's intimate/private parts?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request, euphemism

How to refer to a body's private/intimate parts with one word? Can't seem to find on the web.

As in this sentence, for instance:

> Hey, please stop shaking your **the word**.

More looking for "flamboyant" words that can be used in funny contexts.

Comment: Genitals is the word for the sexual organs.

Comment: Your mouth is also a private part. Do you want that to count?

Comment: Humorous and flamboyant words for genitalia can be found by searching for euphemisms. One of George Carlin's routines includes a list of euphemisms. Jasper Carrott has one too.  My favourite euphemisms are 'lady garden' and 'gentleman sausage'.

Comment: BrE: naughty bits.

Comment: What exactly was he shaking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have two options for this. In general conversation - regular to formal environments - you'll want to use "genitals":

> Please, stop shaking your **genitals**.

If you're talking to little kids, though, or in a much more colloquial setting you can use "privates":

> Please, stop shaking your **privates**.

You do have more playful options:

- **Family Jewels** - for guys only.
- **Pecker** - More common in British English, but I think Americans would still get it. Only for guys.

While looking for more answers to your question, I found something perfect. Here are [2,600 words for male genitals](http://timeglider.com/timeline/194b572e19fd461b) and [a couple of thousand words for female genitals](http://timeglider.com/timeline/07f47d6b843da763) spread out on a timeline over the last ~120 years or so. Here is a screenshot - it's really quite exhaustive:

[image]

Comment: Alex, thanks for your reply. Are there any slang, maybe jargon or just sarcastic words for privates/genitals? To be honest I know these, was more looking for curious, joking or some flamboyant ways to call body parts. Will probably edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @ArmanMcHitarian yes, there definitely are. But they are typically more specific to the separate genders - the all-encompassing words are more scientific and less slangy. Which gender's words are you interested in?

Comment: Alex, both. The thing is that, thinking about this question I was going by the words we use in my native languages (Armenian 1st native, Russian 2nd) and even though the languages are totally different we have "gender-agnostic" words to refer to the intimate parts of the body. "причиндалы, прелести" and "բարեմասնություն". Kind of "smt that is attached to your body/sticks out of it/'fine or nice parts' in a single word (think of part - parties, so it's like fine-fines)". Hope this helps. But as you said, if you can think of one for women and one for men in English will be appreciated.

Comment: @ArmanMcHitarian ah! great - my first language was Russian. The Russian word you gave reminded me of an English word. There is actually a more playful word for this - "family jewels" is used in place of genitals. Though I've heard it used mostly for guys.

Comment: In BrE for males **meat and two veg**, **fishing tackle**; for women below the waist: **fanny**, not to be confused with AmE fanny meaning butt (two sides of the same coin); above the waist: **baps** (buns which are similar in shape to AmE hamburger buns, but bigger)

Comment: @Peter, and Alex(wow, мир тесен и прелестен :) ), tx, guys.

Comment: Regarding "pecker". I'm sure Americans get it no problem. From System Of A Down's IEAIAIO - "Peter's pecker picked another pickle-bearing pussy pepper." :) Always wanted to shout this :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about bits that can be shaken (i.e. dangly bits) you could use "tockley" but it is a mostly Australian slang term so may not work for your audience.

I don't know of any word to refer to a labia that could be shaken.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's try one of these (only for guys):
Hey, please stop shaking your "package".
or
Hey, please stop shaking that "third leg".
Hey, please stop shaking your "middle leg".
And then there is "willy": Hey, please stop shaking "willy".
(I'm a guy - sometimes I say it to myself.)